# Checking all checkboxes in a table using jQuery

Tags: jquery, select, checkbox, html-table

My table looks like the following :

```
<table id="tableOne" class="yui">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>
                <div><input type="checkbox" /></div>
            </th>
            <th>
                <div>Name</div>
            </th>
            <th>
                <div>English</div>
            </th>
            <th>
                <div>Spanish</div>
            </th>
            <th>
                <div>Math</div>
            </th>
            <th>
                <div>History</div>
            </th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <div><input type="checkbox" /></div>
            </td>
            <td>
                <div>Bob Smith</div>
            </td>
            <td>
                <div>80</div>
            </td>
            <td>
                <div>70</div>
            </td>
            <td>
                <div><input type="checkbox" /></div>
            </td>
            <td>
                <div><input type="checkbox" /></div>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <div><input type="checkbox" /></div>
            </td>
            <td>
                <div>George Jones</div>
            </td>
            <td>
                <div>90</div>
            </td>
            <td>88</div>
            </td>
            <td>
                <div><input type="checkbox" /></div>
            </td>
            <td>
                <div><input type="checkbox" /></div>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

I am using the following javascript to check/uncheck all checkboxes in the first column on click of the checkbox in the header.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#tableOne thead tr th:first input:checkbox").click(function() {
        var checkedStatus = this.checked;
        $("#tableOne tbody tr td:first-child input:checkbox").each(function() {
            this.checked = checkedStatus;
        });
    });
});
```

It isn't working. When I click on the checkbox of the header, all the checkboxes in the first column aren't getting selected. I know I am doing something wrong here. Because the `<tr>` tags are in `<div>` and I need to provide this `<div>` somewhere while selecting. But I can't figure out exactly where to put in this `div` in the Javascript. I have tried out a few combinations, but they don't seem to work.

Help please.

EDIT : I have multiple tables in HTML page and I want only this table to be affected. Also, only the checkboxes from the first column need to be checked.

EDIT AGAIN : Sorry, My table is getting rendered in the above manner. Changed the table html.

Comment: Your code is working here: **Made a demo for you** http://jsfiddle.net/5XFrc/1/

Comment: I just tried it out and it worked in chrome: http://jsfiddle.net/WQfdg/ don't know about other browsers though.

Comment: I don't think `div` inside a `tr` is valid though :s

Comment: Doesn't work for me, I am using IE 9. Even the fiddle isn't working for me. o.O

Comment: I'd start by removing all the invalid divs, especially if using "td:first-child". Not the problem, but you don't need the `.each()` loop, just say `$("#tableOne tbody tr td:first-child input:checkbox").prop("checked",checkedStatus)` and it will set the property for all matching checkboxes. (Or use `.attr()` if on jQuery < 1.6.)

Comment: Actually the table is getting generated dynamically. What I provided is actually the rendered version of the table.

Answer (score 1):

Your HTML code is broken, which will make your code fail in some browsers, including Internet Explorer. You can't have div tags around your table cells.

Different browsers handle the broken code differently. Firefox for example moves the div tags outside the table, so there they don't break your code. Internet Explorer moves the table cells outside the div tags, but there is still a broken nameless tag inside the table rows before the table cells, so the `:first-child` selector doesn't work as the table cell is not the first child in the table row.

If you remove the div tags, it works fine: http://jsfiddle.net/Guffa/jKxNF/1/

Tested in IE9, Firefox, Chrome, Safari, Opera

Comment: I know it's not a good option to put table rows inside div tags, but I am helpless in this case. The code is an existing one and cannot be changed. The div tags actually render the css styles to the table rows. I know it works without div tag, but I am trying to get it work with the div tags.

Comment: @CRMJunkie: Then you are in for browser specific hell. Different browsers render the broken HTML in different ways, so you have to test your code in every browser that you can get your hands on (including IE6, IE7, IE8, IE9, which is a PITA as you can only have one IE version installed at a time...) to make sure that it works. You just have to experiment with different ways of finding the checkboxes to find one that works will all browsers. Adding a class to the checkboxes should make them easier to locate, though.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, your HTML isn't valid because the TR tags are in DIVs, but that shouldn't be a problem for jQuery. I can't see anything all that wrong with your code, but it could definitely be simplified. The following approach should work:

```
$("#tableOne thead input:checkbox").click(function() {
    $("#tableOne tbody input:checkbox").prop('checked', $(this).is(':checked'));
});
```

Note that you don't have to specify each child node. `$('#tableOne thead :checkbox')` will find all checkboxes in the `thead`, regardless of whether or note those are in any nested child tags. However, `$('#tableOne thead > :checkbox')` would mandate that the checkbox be an immediate child of the `thead`.

Comment: This code selects all checkboxes in the table. I want only the checkboxes in the first column to be checked.

Comment: As long as we're simplifying, `$(this).is(':checked')` can be simplified to `this.checked`.

Comment: @nnnnnn: I usually don't mind the jQuery round-trip. `this.className` works in some browsers and not in others, `$(this).attr('class')` works in all. To me, the single greatest benefit of jQuery is not having to deal with different browser implementations. The fact that the particular property `checked` doesn't happen to have any such inconsistencies in behavior across the major browsers is not a very compelling reason to make an exception to this practice, in my opinion.

Comment: @CRMJunkie: Sorry, I missed that requirement. In that case, I think you'll have to go with Guffa's answer. Since the markup isn't valid, you're pretty much leaving it for the user agent to interpret freely, and it's quite conceivable that some browsers wouldn't have a notion of a first column in code that isn't a valid table.

Comment: I'm curious: which browser(s) don't support `this.className`?

Comment: @nnnnnn: older IE, you have to use `this.cssClass` instead. Only it's never "instead" but rather "also, with a lot of wrapping conditions". Hence jQuery.

Comment: @nnnnnn: Actually, looking back at that I can't seem to find sources to verify it. I could be mistaken here. But that was just an example anyway, the argument is the same. If the above is uncertain, I'll throw in `this.cssFloat` instead, where IE uses (used?) `this.styleFloat`.

Answer (score 0):

// all checkboxes are empty at first

```
var checked = false;
$(element).click(function(){
      if (checked){
          $("#tableOne").find("input[type=checkbox]").removeAttr("checked");
          checked = false;
      }
      else{
          $("#formId").find("input[type=checkbox]").setAttr("checked", "checked");
          checked = true;
      }
});
```

Comment: I suppose this will select/unselect all checkboxes in the form? That is not my motive though. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I think this is the most simple way just give chk as ID prefix like chkPresent123 etc

```
$("#invoiceReceiptTable > tbody > tr").each(function (i, el) {

       $($(this).find("input[id^=chk]")).prop('checked', true);

    }
});
```

and this is how you can get all checked check boxes. all checked ids will be in $IDs

```
$IDs = $("#invoiceReceiptTable input:checkbox:checked").map(function () {
    var id = $(this).attr("id");
    return id;
}).get();
```